# How to mock a service injected in a domain class from a Controller Test Class?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, spring-security, mocking

I have a domain class which extends an abstract class which injects the [spring security core plugin](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/) service.

```
class Extra extends WithOwner {
    String name
}

abstract class WithOwner {
    transient springSecurityService
    User user

    def getCurrentUser() {
        return springSecurityService.currentUser
    }

    def beforeValidate() {
        if(!user) {
             user = getCurrentUser()
        }
    }

    Boolean isLoggedUserTheOwner(){
        return (user?.id == getCurrentUser()?.id)
    }
}
```

I want to implement a controller test.

```
@TestFor(ExtraController)
@Mock([Extra, User, UserRole, Role])
class ExtraControllerTests {

    void testEdit() {
        def utils = new TestUtils()
        def user1 = utils.saveUser1()

        populateValidParams(params)
        def extra = new Extra(params)
        extra.user = user1
        assert extra.save() != null

        params.id = extra.id


        def model = controller.edit() // Line 69
        assert model.extraInstance == extra
    }
}
```

If I run the above test I get:

test-app ExtraController.testEdit --unit --echoOut
| Running 1 unit test... 1 of 1
--Output from testEdit--
| Failure:  testEdit(com.softamo.movilrural.ExtraControllerTests)
|  java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'currentUser' on null object
    at com.softamo.movilrural.WithOwner.getCurrentUser(WithOwner.groovy:8)
    at com.softamo.movilrural.WithOwner.isLoggedUserTheOwner(WithOwner.groovy:18)
    at com.softamo.movilrural.ExtraController.edit(ExtraController.groovy:39)
    at com.softamo.movilrural.ExtraControllerTests.testEdit(ExtraControllerTests.groovy:69)
| Completed 1 unit test, 1 failed in 853ms

I have tried without success to mock the security service like this:

```
Extra.metaClass.springSecurityService = new MockSpringSecurityService(user1)
```

or even mocking the method

```
Extra.metaClass.getCurrentUser = { return user1 }
```

Any idea how could I work around this issue.

Comment: Hello! I'm stuck with the same problem. Have you worked out a solution for your question? Or maybe you have a sideway to inject a service inside a domain object without unit-test autowiring?

Comment: Any luck with this issue?, facing same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Grails 2.x supports defining spring beans for test environments using 'defineBeans' closure.
It supports dependency injection in controllers etc, I am not sure if it works for domain objects as well. Theoretically it should be consistent across domain objects/controllers/services

See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#testing - The 'Testing Spring Beans' section.

Comment: I've tried this but does not work. No idea how to set it up for domain classes. defineBeans {
springSecurityService(new MockSpringSecurityService(user1))
}

Comment: You dont need to do new MockSpringSecurityService() when you define a spring bean, just springSecurityService(MockSpringSecurityService)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
controller.springSecurityService = new SpringSecurityService()
```

If you want to mock getCurrentUser method in this service:

```
controller.springSecurityService.metaClass.getCurrentUser = { -> return user1 }
```

I'm not sure if you can ommit `->` in a line above, so test it. If you want to clear this mocked method after use or before another test case use this:

```
controller.springSecutiryService.metaClass = null
```

Comment: This explains how to inject the service into controller, his question is how to mock the service in a domain object.

Comment: Just for the record, you can omit the `->` and simplify it to just `getCurrentUser = { user1 }`

Answer (score 1):

I found a great article about this problem: [Inject springSecurityService Into Grails Domain Class for Controller Unit Testing](http://www.block-consult.com/blog/2011/08/17/inject-spring-security-service-into-domain-class-for-controller-unit-testing)